# Should I use a thread-safe map implementation with DateTimeFormatter?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, datetimeformatter

Please help me figure it out, I think I'm confused. I have a class contains HashMap<String, DateTimeFormatter> that is populated when the application starts.

```
public class DateService{
   private final Map<String, DateTimeFormatter> map;
   public PeopleService(String pattern){
     map = new HashMap<String, DateTimeFormatter>();
     map.put(pattern, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)); //it is only test example
   }
}
```

Should I make it `ConcurrentHashMap` or `volatile` to convert the date into multiple threads?

A similar question if I want to use `List<DateTimeFormatter>`  to convert dates in multiple threads

Comment: Are new elements added after that constructor initialization?  If no, then only reading from the Map would be thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

If your intent is a single instance, pre-populated, and unmodified, then the following code should be thread-safe.

If `final` and unmodifiable, you can provide direct access to the map, if that is helpful in your code situation.

```java
public class DateService
{
    // Member fields.
    public final Map< String, DateTimeFormatter > formatsByPurpose;
    
    // Constructor
    public DateService( … )
    {
        this.formatsByPurpose = 
                Map.of(
                        "gui" , DateTimeFormatter.of( … ).withLocale( … ) ,
                        "print" , DateTimeFormatter.of( … ).withLocale( … ) ,
                        "json" , DateTimeFormatter.of( … ).withLocale( … ) ,
                        "html" , DateTimeFormatter.of( … ).withLocale( … ) ,
                );
        …
    }
}
```

If you intend to have only a single map created, but may modify its contents, then perhaps this code.

We use `Map.of` here for its convenient literals-syntax, but pass it to a constructor for another map.

Notice that we define the member field as `ConcurrentMap` to advertise to the reader its thread-safety, and to double-check our code to ensure we assign only an object that implements `ConcurrentMap`.

```java
public class DateService
{
    // Member fields.
    public final ConcurrentMap< String, DateTimeFormatter > formatsByPurpose;
    
    // Constructor
    public DateService( … )
    {
        Map< String , DateTimeFormatter > map = 
                Map.of(
                        "gui" , DateTimeFormatter.of( … ).withLocale( … ) ,
                        "print" , DateTimeFormatter.of( … ).withLocale( … ) ,
                        "json" , DateTimeFormatter.of( … ).withLocale( … ) ,
                        "html" , DateTimeFormatter.of( … ).withLocale( … ) ,
                );
        this.formatsByPurpose = new ConcurrentHashMap<>( map ) ;
        …
    }
}
```

If you intend to possibly replace the entire map with another map object, then use [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) (or, alternatively, mark it `volatile`).

Notice the `…Ref` added to the member field name to remind the reader of it being an atomic reference, meaning it takes us one step away from the payload we actually care about (the map).

We mark the atomic reference as `final` to prevent our member field from ever being assigned to any other `AtomicReference` object. So the payload (the map object’s reference) may be changed out, but its container (the `AtomicReference` object) remains fixed.

```java
public class DateService
{
    // Member fields.
    public final AtomicReference< ConcurrentMap< String, DateTimeFormatter > > formatsByPurposeRef = new AtomicReference<>() ;
    
    // Constructor
    public DateService( … )
    {
        ConcurrentMap< String , DateTimeFormatter > map = 
                Map.of(
                        "gui" , DateTimeFormatter.of( … ).withLocale( … ) ,
                        "print" , DateTimeFormatter.of( … ).withLocale( … ) ,
                        "json" , DateTimeFormatter.of( … ).withLocale( … ) ,
                        "html" , DateTimeFormatter.of( … ).withLocale( … ) ,
                );
        this.formatsByPurposeRef.set( new ConcurrentHashMap<>( map ) ) ;
        …
    }
}
```

To modify the map stored away inside an atomic reference, go through the atomic.

```java
myDateService.formatsByPurposeRef.get().remove( "html" ) ;  // Optionally capture the returned (and now removed) `DateTimeFormatter` object.
```

Caveat: All that code is untested, off the top of my head.

## Details

Regarding [thread-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety), two considerations:

- `DateTimeFormatter` objects themselves are guaranteed by the the Javadoc to be thread-safe. Being immutable contributes towards being thread-safe. To quote the Javadoc: ***Implementation Requirements:** This class is immutable and thread-safe.*
- Any `Map` implementation that you (a) populate ahead of usage, and (b) do not modify (no puts, no removes), is thread-safe for retrieval.

So key part here, which you did not explain, is your intention to (a) modify or not modify the map, and (b) replace or not replace the map.

- If you might possibly modify the map, be sure to use a thread-safe implementation of `Map`. The `HashMap` implementation is *not* thread-safe under possibly modified. Use a `Map` class that implements [`ConcurrentMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html). Java comes bundled with two such implementations: `ConcurrentHashMap` & `ConcurrentSkipListMap`. You may find third-party ones, perhaps in *Eclipse Collections* and/or *Google Guava*.
- If you intend to *not* modify the map, use an implementation that is [unmodifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#unmodifiable). Then, no thread-safety worries.

> Should I make it `ConcurrentHashMap`

Only if you intend to modify the elements of the map.

> Should I make it … volatile

Not if you instantiate (once, and only once) and populate before any possible usage. I personally prefer this approach. Instantiating & populating in a constructor is one good way to do this.

If your intention is to instantiate a single `Map` object, and keep it unmodifiable, then two tips:

- Mark the `Map` field as `final` to ensure that another map object’s reference is never assigned to that variable.
- Use `Map.of` or `Map.copyOf` to ensure your map cannot be modified.

If you intend to switch out one map object for another during runtime, then you definitely have an "visibility" issue. In that case, you can either (a) mark the field `volatile` or (b) use an `AtomicReference` variable to hold the current map object’s reference. I personally prefer the latter because I like how `Atomic…` screams out to the reader that we are protecting a resource under concurrent access. Having to use the `Atomic…` methods everywhere keeps us aware of being in a multi-threaded situation.